# Eclipse + Cygwin + Make: Windows path problems

Tags: eclipse, makefile, cygwin

I am experiencing different behavior when running make for a Cygwin C project in Eclipse vs the Cygwin shell.

The problem is that path names are being converted to windows paths.

My makefile:

```
all:
    pwd
    cd .; pwd
```

Running make in Cygwin shell (correct):

```
pwd
/cygdrive/c/myproject
cd .; pwd
/cygdrive/c/myproject
```

Running build in CDT (New Makefile Project from Existing Code, Cygwin toolchain):

```
make all 
pwd
/cygdrive/c/myproject
cd .; pwd
C:\myproject
```

It sees that using '.' (or '..') cause the path to be "converted" to a windows path.  Any suggestions?

Comment: could you provide us some output?

Comment: I have included the output of building under the cygwin shell and building from Eclipse.  The flawed output is the line 'C:\myproject'

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that compound command `cd .; pwd` is executing via shell subprocess, so this shell process may have different `$PATH` variable set. If there're another `pwd` in your `$PATH`, it will be called instead cygwin's one. For example, `pwd` from gnuwin32 prints windows' style paths.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, if you are gonna run scripts, use a shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

Second, everything you need to know on this specific topic seems to be here, for free:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/ch07.pdf

Use something similar to

```
cygpath `pwd`
```

instead