# Always have to define PATH variable in Eclipse on windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, variables, path, cygwin

I've recently started using eclipse to develop c++ applications(or at least im trying to) but I'm having trouble because something seems to be wrong with my PATH variable, as in order to get eclipse to compile my c++ applications correctly I have to go to the projects properties and manually add the cygwin64 bin folder's path as the PATH variable EVERY time, this isn't a HUGE deal, but it'd be nice if i could just set it as default or something, I've tried setting the PATH default in the advanced windows settings but to no avail..

Comment: Is there a way to echo the value of the PATH variable within the context of the program?  I wonder if the path you set in windows is being overwritten.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: The PATH is an environment variable.  It is possible that eclipse is overwriting the global PATH variable and supplying a different one for the program, thus eliminating the changes you performed in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried setting the PATH default in the advanced windows settings but to no avail..

If you have done that, then you would need to open a new cmd Windows, check that the PATH is correct (type `set PATH`) and launch eclipse from there.

Then you should see the cygwin tool chain will be shown when you open a new c/cpp project wizard.

[image: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_-eF6MRzeanE/Sd3297X5hFI/AAAAAAAAAHE/M6cM8ZDYNA0/s400/cdt_cygwin_toolchain.png]

(from this [blog post](http://wyding.blogspot.fr/2009/04/setup-cygwin-toolchain-in-eclipse-cdt.html))

More on:

- "[Eclipse + Cygwin + Make: Windows path problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17433225/6309)"
- "[How to deal with Eclipse CDT+Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10469520/6309)"